# Android emulator in Xamarin has been loading forever

Tags: android, xamarin

I am starting to develop apps in Xamarin using Visual Studio 2015. What I currently have is the KitKat 4.4. I was trying the WeatherApp sample I found in MSDN. I made a Native Portable app as the first step. VS successfully made 4 projects but I removed the iOS because I do not have a test device for it. I selected the Droid project as the start up one and ran it using 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone (Android 4.4 - API 19).

The output window started to show some messages

```
1>Starting deploy 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Starting emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
1>Validating emulator arguments...
1>Determining if emulator is already running...
1>Preparing virtual machine...
```

But the log stucked there for an hour. I read somewhere that I should try running the emulator using the app below (screen shot) but it's been like that more than 4 hours already. I have already done all my house chores and still loading.. **What could be the issue**? I have also tried running VS as Administrator mode but still no luck :(

[image]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ok simple answer ... after looking the System Event, I noticed this error "**Miniport Hyper-V Virtual Switch Extension Adapter #3, {d61a03f8-7f74-4d32-82f2-da1c23eb98fd}, had event 76**" I tried removing my USB WiFi adapter, and it's now working as expected.